# Sending passProps to specific components in React-Native-Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am currently using react-native-navigation (Wix) and RN 0.48.3, without flux or redux.

Currently I am focusing on making the backend handle pretty much all the logic, so I am sending "actions" that the mobile components execute. One of them is to open an internal link, which I can add some passProps from the backend.

Now, the new screen could have multiple components and I am just sending a bunch of properties to a screen.

My question is, what is the best way to send specific props to specific components? I am currently thinking on sending a JSON structure with an ID which I can match to a ref in the final screen.

I am open to ideas. I am not using redux or flux and I´d like to keep it that way but I am willing to add it to the project if that makes things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a better alternative please let me know, but I have solved it like this.

I have a ScreenComponent which actually enriches and add features to all my child components like analytics and some other helpers.

Basically, I am adding a ref to each component that I am adding on each screen and then I use passProps like this:

```
screenParams: {
                      screen: 'AudioScreen',
                      passProps: {
                          componentProps: {
                              audioCard: {
                                  title:'Audio Title',
                                  subtitle:'Audio Subtitle',
                                  image:{imageSource},
                                  audioSource:{audioSource}                                                        
                              }   
                          }
                      }
                  }
```

componentProps is the object that I use and in my screen I do this in my componentWillMount:

```
this._children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
            let extraProps = {
                eventEmitter: this._eventEmitter
            };
            if (child.ref != null && self.props.componentProps && self.props.componentProps[child.ref]){
                extraProps = self.getHelper().concat(extraProps, self.props.componentProps[child.ref])
            }
            return React.cloneElement(child, extraProps);
        });
```

As you can see, I am adding an eventEmitter to each child, so I can communicate to my parent screen to show modals, error alerts, etc. The helper is a module I have that just merges two objects.

That way, I can send props to the screen, props to each component and also I can override everything from the backend.

So far it has been working great.
Hope it helps